# How to add p-value table to survival plot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, survival-analysis, survival

I have the data as follows:

```
library(survival)
library(survminer)
data(aml)
aml$x <- as.character(aml$x)
aml[10,3] <- 'SuperMaintained'
aml[11,3] <- 'SuperMaintained'
aml[22,3] <- 'SuperMaintained'
aml[23,3] <- 'SuperMaintained'
aml$x <- factor(aml$x, levels = c('Nonmaintained','Maintained','SuperMaintained'))

fit <- survfit(Surv(time, status) ~ x, data = aml)

ggsurvplot(fit, conf.int = FALSE, surv.median.line = c('hv'), data = aml,  pval = TRUE, risk.table = FALSE)

[![Survivalplot][1]][1]

res=pairwise_survdiff(Surv(time, status) ~ x, data = aml)
res$p.value
```

Output look like this

```
                Nonmaintained   Maintained
Maintained      0.085155296     NA
SuperMaintained 0.007303126     0.0851553
```

How do I add this table to the main survival plot?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add a custom text `annotate` by adding a `ggplot` function to the "plot" (p1$plot) object saved in your `ggsurvplot` object. You can use the function `annotate` with `geom=table` thanks to the `ggpmisc` package and pass your table to the `label` argument like this:

```r
library(survival)
library(survminer)
library(ggpmisc)

data("aml")
aml$x <- as.character(aml$x)
aml[10,3] <- 'SuperMaintained'
aml[11,3] <- 'SuperMaintained'
aml[22,3] <- 'SuperMaintained'
aml[23,3] <- 'SuperMaintained'
aml$x <- factor(aml$x, levels = c('Nonmaintained','Maintained','SuperMaintained'))

fit <- survfit(Surv(time, status) ~ x, data = aml)

res=pairwise_survdiff(Surv(time, status) ~ x, data = aml)
table <- res$p.value

p1 <- ggsurvplot(fit, conf.int = FALSE, surv.median.line = c('hv'), data = aml,  pval = TRUE, risk.table = FALSE) 

p1$plot +
  annotate(geom = "table", x = 140, y = 0.9, label = list(as.data.frame(table)))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-08-19 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Please note: your "table" should be a `tibble` or `data.frame`, so I used `as.data.frame()`.

**Add row names to table**

You can use `rownames_to_column` to include the rownames in your table like this:

```r
# Create table for in plot
table <- as.data.frame(table)
table <- rownames_to_column(table)
colnames(table)[1] <- ""

p1 <- ggsurvplot(fit, conf.int = FALSE, surv.median.line = c('hv'), data = aml,  pval = TRUE, risk.table = FALSE) 

p1$plot +
  annotate(geom = "table", x = 140, y = 0.9, label = list(table))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-08-19 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: It's working . But I missed the `row.names` of the table

Comment: @batman, I added some code for that. You can use `rownames_to_column` to include the row names in your table.